# Can the timestamp be null in a core audio render callback?

Tags: ios, swift4, core-audio

I have an iOS workout app that needs to stay running (and playing audio) while in the background. Sadly, the only way to accomplish this, that I know of, is to play an inaudible sound through Core Audio.

One user is experiencing a repeating crash that I can't reproduce in my simulators. (They have an iPhone 5, iOS 10.)  The crash report in Xcode points to a line that I've never seen crash before. Can `timestamp` be null in the render callback?

```
private func render(ctx: UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
                    ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
                    timeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                    bus: UInt32,
                    nFrames: UInt32,
                    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus
{
    guard let ioData = ioData else { return noErr }
    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(ioData)
    guard let bufferData = abl[0].mData else { return noErr }

    let impl = Unmanaged<MyClass>.fromOpaque(ctx).takeUnretainedValue()

    let buf: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32> = bufferData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self)
    // **** Crash appears to pointing to this next line. 
    var t: Int = Int(timeStamp.pointee.mSampleTime) % impl.samples.count
    for i in 0..<Int(nFrames) {
        buf[i] = impl.samples[t]
        t += 1
        if t >= impl.samples.count { t = 0 }
    }
    ...
```